# Display multiline column in the Gallery view

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, custom-list, json-formatting, gallery-view

In my SPO List there is a multiline column (Multiple lines of text). The column is not visible in the Gallery view. Is there anything I can do about this? Some JSON maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this. I had to manually add the column to the JSON code in the gallery view:

```
{
        "elmType": "div",
        "attributes": {
          "class": "sp-card-lastTextColumnContainer"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "p",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "ms-fontColor-neutralSecondary sp-card-label"
            },
            "txtContent": "[!ColumnName.DisplayName]"
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "sp-card-content sp-card-formatterRef"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "columnFormatterReference": "[$ColumnName]"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
```

Comment: I had the same problem, but the multi-line text didn't wrap.  I had to add the following in a style section: `"word-break": "normal"`